# Need assistance with designing a loop to iterate 10 times and keeping a running total of numbers entered

Tags: linux, bash, loops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

"Design a loop that asks the user to enter a number. The loop should iterate 10
times and keep a running total of the numbers entered."

This is the prompt I'm working with. I'm using bash code in Windows Subsystem for Linux. It's an online class and my professor is currently no help because of the start of spring break. I'm not entirely sure what to do because I am new to programming in general (joined the class kind of late).

I'm expecting a loop that should iterate 10 times. It also has to keep a running total of the numbers entered. I know the basics, but when I tried it out myself it felt like I was just doing spaghetti code or something.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you already tried?

At a bash prompt, try typing the following: `help for`, `help while`, `help read`. `for` and `while` can do the looping, and `read` can prompt the user for input.

Comment: Some resources that might be helpful to get the answer(s) you want: [tour], [ask], [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3124333). As your question stands you are effectively asking us to do your homework, which is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the read function with the `-p` option which prints a prompt. The variable at the end will store the user's answer.

Then you set an initial count variable to 1 (or 0) if you prefer.

Then the while loop says "keep looping as long as this thing is true", where "this thing" is the stuff inside the `[[ ]]`. `-le` means "less than or equal to".

`((cnt++))` means on each loop to increment the `cnt` variable.

```bash
# prompt user for input
read -p "Please enter the number of loops: " max_cnt

# set initial count 
cnt=1

# iterate over the loop and print the value until max_cnt
while [[ $cnt -le $max_cnt ]]; do
  echo "Loop '$cnt' of '$max_cnt'"
  ((cnt++))
done
```

For example:

```bash
$ read -p "Please enter the number of loops: " max_cnt
Please enter the number of loops: 10
$ cnt=1
$ while [[ $cnt -le $max_cnt ]]; do   echo "Loop '$cnt' of '$max_cnt'" ;   ((cnt++)); done
Loop '1' of '10'
Loop '2' of '10'
Loop '3' of '10'
Loop '4' of '10'
Loop '5' of '10'
Loop '6' of '10'
Loop '7' of '10'
Loop '8' of '10'
Loop '9' of '10'
Loop '10' of '10'
```